# I'm trying to find the pattern in the text,what going wrong?

Tags: c++, algorithm

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string s1="panamabananas";
    string s2="nana";
    int i,j,k=0;
    string count="";
    for(i=0;i<s1.length();i++)
    {
        k=0;

        if(s2[k]==s1[i]);
        {                           
            count+=s2[k];

            for(j=i+1;j<i+s2.length();j++)
            {       
                    k++;
                    if(s2[k]==s1[j])
                    {
                        count+=s2[k];
                        cout<<"it is: "<<count<<endl;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        count="";
                        break;
                    }                   
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"the matched string is "<<count;
    return 0;
}
```

The pattern s2 is searched if it exists in text s1. And a counter is managed to write the content of pattern match. The counter must be equal to `nana` in the end i.e it indicates the `nana` exist in the text `panamabananas`.
I don't understand what's going wrong here.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: It's not clear what you really want as output and really you are just saying "My code doesn't work", but one thought - if you are looking for substrings, say `"nana"` in another string just go to the length of the other string minus the length of "`nana"` `for (i = 0; i<s1.length() - s2.length(); i++)` - there's no point in running beyond a possible match length, which will give you "nana in the end" for your example

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you reset count even after finding the pattern, because you do nothing to break out of the outer for loop and it continues. It compares nana in the first string with nana in the second, finds the match, falls out of the inner for loop, but then goes back into the outer for loop. Later it will get to the last n in s1, trigger the if statement again, and try to match "nas" with "nana". When the s doesn't match the n, it resets count to "".

Anyway, if you add an if statement checking if k is the length of s2, then you can return immediately once you find the pattern.

Anyway, that's what it looks like from looking at your code. I do recommend going through it with a debugger that lets you step through your code, so you can see what's going on as it happens.